# How to prepare image segmentation data to train region proposal network for extracting a bounding box around object automatically?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, caffe, pycaffe

i have installed `pycaffe` and I wanna get a bounding box around my object in test images. I have only ground truth of manual segmentation. I understood that [Fast R-CNN](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~tvg/publications/talks/fast-rcnn-slides.pdf) can give a region proposal. My question is that have you tried to prepare your data for training with Fast R-CNN? If yes, considering the image and ground truth for segmentation that I have, how can I prepare my data for detecting the bounding box and train and fine-tune this network on my data?

As long as I know the data that you are going to train the network with, should be exactly similar to the pre-trained model. If you know any code for this kind of data preparation, could you please share with me?